# Delete all except n first elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a slideshow and I want to ensure that there are not more than 5 elements (one active and two preloaded in each direction).
How can I select all elements except the first/last 5 elements?

Right now I have:

```
while ($holder.children().length > 5) {
    $holder.children().first().remove();
}
```

But this is not very suitable because I want to fade the elements out before removing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) to select first five like

```
$('selector:lt(5)');
```

Use *negative* value with [:gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to select last.

```
$('selector:gt(-5)');
```

Comment: So I will use the `:not` selector to get all EXCEPT these 5 elements?

Comment: Yes you can do that but there are many other ways, you have to decide which one suits you most.